# Implementing a one-sided platform using an SKSpriteNode

Tags: ios, ios7, sprite-kit

I'm trying to implement a one sided platform using an SKSpriteNode. The way I'm going about it is to try and switch out the collisionBitMask when the hero is under the platform, and switch it back on when over.

My platform physics body is configured like this:

```
platform.physicsBody.dynamic = NO;
platform.physicsBody.categoryBitMask = platformCategory;
platform.physicsBody.collisionBitMask = heroCategory;
```

My hero like this

```
hero.physicsBody.categoryBitMask = heroCategory;
hero.physicsBody.contactTestBitMask = enemyProjectileCategory|monsterCategory;
hero.physicsBody.collisionBitMask = groundCategory;
```

I have an update method that checks before each simulation step on the platform that checks this:

```
if (self.position.y < self.hero.position.y) {
    NSLog(@"setting collision to hero");
    self.physicsBody.collisionBitMask = heroCategory;
} else {
    NSLog(@"removing collision");
    self.physicsBody.collisionBitMask = 0;
}
```

My categories look like this:

```
typedef enum : uint8_t {
    friendlyProjectileCategory = 1,
    enemyProjectileCategory = 2,
    monsterCategory = 4,
    heroCategory = 8,
    groundCategory = 16,
    platformCategory = 32
} physicsCategories;
```

The issue is that I'm seeing the collision bit mask  correctly flipped as my hero jumps over the platform (he correctly goes through from the bottom), but then he falls right through it (supposed to collide) even though I am seeing the "removing collision" log executing.

Comment: Does the hero collide with the platform if you don't change the collisionBitMask? Try swapping the categoryBitMask instead of the collisionBitMask too.

Comment: I mean swapping the categoryBitMask instead of the collisionBitMask

Comment: ps: position alone won't suffice, you need to consider the bounding boxes of both player and platform. The player is only "above" the platform if his lower bounding box edge is above (or at least equal) to the platform's top bounding box edge. In all other cases the platform needs to be non-collidable, otherwise you'll have problems when the player jumps towards the 1-sided platform from the sides, or the jump ends (velocity.y becomes negative) while the player's bounding box is in contact with the platform's bounding box.

Comment: @LearnCocos2D If I don't change the collisionBitMask the hero does collide. I'll try swapping out the categoryBitMask. Thanks for the input on the position - I'm going to take this into account after I figured out basic contact - to debug I made the hero jump way over the platform to make sure this isn't an issue.

Comment: @godel9 fyi I tried adding the platform to the hero's collision bit mask but still had the same issue.

Comment: @LearnCocos2D It works when I flip the categoryBitMask instead! Thanks again Steffan. You think the reason is sprite kit is somehow caching the collision bit mask?

Comment: not sure but category avoids contact events altogether, collision bits only affect collision resolve as in not allowing bodies to intersect